# Mail sending with codeigniter and gmail account does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail, gmail-api

I a trying to send an email with codeigniter.
here is the content of email.php config file.

```
<?php

$config=
    array(
        'protocol'=>'smtp',
        'useragent'=>'Camerbitcoin',
        'smtp_host'=>'smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_user'=>'myemail@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass'=>'my password',
        'smtp_port'=>'587',
        'mailtype'=>'html',

    );
```

and here the code that send the email.

```
$this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com','Compagny name');
                    $this->email->to('receiver@yahoo.fr');
                    $this->email->subject('Activation link');
                    $this->email->message('Welcome .<br/>');
                    $this->load->view('registration_success');
$this->email->send();
```

no errors are displayed, but the mail is not sent.

Comment: Check the mail error through `$this->email->print_debugger()`

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
```

Comment: so, have you a error output? If you need debug, you try this, $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;

Comment: with this, i have another error : **bold** Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**bold**